# Figures in html have a spot next to them

Tags: html, css, figures

I am trying to organize a gallery using figures, but I keep getting this annoying dot or bullet next to them.  Are there any solutions like "list-style-type:none" for figures?

[image]

Thanks

(had to post a link to picture because I'm not allowed yet)

Comment: Unless you provide us with some code, the only thing I can suggest is to take the white brush and remove the dot from your image. :) `list-style: none` should work though.

Comment: You really need to post some HTML and CSS otherwise your question is essentially useless to anyone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that your images are contained in a list and you need to change the list style to none for the relevant list.

Comment: If I answered the question, please accept the answer, that way people know that the work is done.

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
body ul {
  list-style: none;
}
```

This would apply a none list style for all the lists under the Body element.